# socialtext API programming

Tags: c#, php, web-services, api, rest

I need to consume `socialText API` using php/Java/C# (any of those languages). I went through 
https://www.socialtext.net/st-rest-docs/Tutorial#examples and throughout the internet.

They really don't have a proper documentation it seems
But I was unable to find out a proper way of consuming `socialText` rest API..

I am stuck with logging to `socialText` also.
All I need is logging to `socialText` account and get content from given URL.

Any help I highly appreciate..
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I could get you started with c#.

You can use the `HTTPWebRequest` class to do RESTful call to the `socialText API`.
Then set the required [Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.headers(v=vs.110).aspx) as mentioned in their documentation and then simply make the call.

The response would be `JSON` (as per the documentation), so you will have to create a class (perhaps `MyResponse`) according to it and then [Deserialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674188.aspx) the response received in to your class and use the resulting object as per your needs.

A rough draft of the code would look like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
         throw new Exception(String.Format("Server error (HTTP {0}: {1}).", response.StatusCode, response.StatusDescription));
    var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Response));
    object objResponse = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream());
    MyResponse jsonResponse = objResponse as MyResponse;
    return jsonResponse;
}
```

See this link for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674188.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. But how can i logging to the socialText using code.. ?

Comment: You will have to explore their documentation and the make the appropriate HTTP call as I mentioned. It should not be much different.

Comment: I tried but didn't get any information.... They have not given proper documentation as far as i could see.

Comment: You might contact their support as well